# What is the closed form sum of the convolution of non-zero squares?

Tags: summation, asymptotics, closed-form, convolution

I am trying to do the runtime analysis for a coding problem, and I've found that the total number of operations is equal to:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 (n-i)^2
\end{equation}

- Where n is the size of the grid data in the problem.

I found the sequence for this function on OEIS:

1, 8, 34, 104, 259, 560, 1092, 1968 ... (see full sequence here: https://oeis.org/A033455)

How do I find a closed form equation that gives me the nth value of this sequence?

For context this is the coding problem (if you're curious): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-square-sub-matrix-with-sum-less-than-or-equals-to-k/

And in general, I would appreciate any advice you have on finding closed form equations/functions for sequences on OEIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formulas for $\sum_{i=1}^ni^{k}$, namely [Faulhaber's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) formulas. Quick look gives $O(n^5)$ as complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply those here. Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Expand:

$$ \sum_j j^2(n-j)^2 = \sum_j j^2(n^2 - 2nj + j^2) = \sum_j j^4 - 2n \sum_j j^3 + n^2 \sum_j j^2. $$

Look these formulas up in the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Using C614's formulas the full solutions is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{n^5-n}{30}
\end{equation}